# A listview item in preferences

Tags: android, listview, preferences

I'm new in Android app development! I'm developing an app with settings. I want to divide the settings in categories (like in android system settings). I found preferences, and in particular this guide: http://android-journey.blogspot.it/2010/01/for-almost-any-application-we-need-to.html
So I create my activity and the xml file, no problem. But I want to add an item like listview that when I touch it, it opens another activity. Is it possible to do?

Comment: OnItemClickListener is what you are looking for I believe

Comment: Yes, sure! But how can I implement listView in xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to create settings with preferences - items of your "listview" and set actions to them: Intents to your another settings activities.

```
private void createRateAppPrefListener() {

    Intent marketIntent = getMarketIntent(mContext);
    String rateAppKey = getString(R.string.pref_rate_app_key);
    Preference rateAppPref = findPreference(rateAppKey);
    if (rateAppPref != null) {
        rateAppPref.setIntent(marketIntent);
    }
}

private Intent getMarketIntent(Context context) {
    String appPackageName = context.getPackageName();
    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName));
    marketIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    return marketIntent;
}
```

shortly

```
Intent intent = ...
Preference pref = findPreference(getString(R.string.your_pref_key));
pref.setIntent(intent);
```

Youtube preference, for example
[image: example screenshots]

**UPDATE:**
It is not a listview or listitem it is standart preference, defined in xml file

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Preference
        android:key="@string/pref_rate_app_key"
        android:summary="@string/pref_rate_app_summary"
        android:title="@string/pref_rate_app_title" />

 ...
```

But it can be simpler

```
    <Preference
        android:summary="@string/pref_licenses_summary"
        android:title="@string/pref_licenses_title">

            <intent android:action="com.mdhelper.cardiojournal.view.activities.LicensesActivity" />

    </Preference>
```

Just add intent definition in your preference xml

Comment: Ok, but how do I implement the listView item in the xml file?

Comment: @Damien I did update my answer. Forget about manually listview in preferenceactivity! It makes automatically by your xml file